# How can I run only one instance of Thunar?

Tags: thunar

I have `Ubuntu 20`.

I want to run `only one` Thunar instance for user.

I tried: `wmctrl` - not work, thunar window is not in result

How to do this?

Comment: I can think of an option with a script replacing thunar from /usr/bin, but it's not very pretty

Comment: `wmctrl` on its own just displays the help page for me. So probably you tried something else? I use `jumpapp` to launch or switch to if it is already running. It is a bash script that uses `wmctrl`.

Comment: @vanadium I had more of a custom script in mind, something to grep through the processes of a user and if the real thunar binary is running to exit, otherwise run it. by the way, thunar allows only one window if not run by a terminal

Answer (score 1):

**Launch or Switch To**

If the application by itself does not allow to connect to a running instance when it is run a second time, you can use `wmctrl` to switch to a running instance if present.

Following one liner will do:

```
wmctrl -x -a Thunar || thunar
```

This runs `wmctrl`, which will switch (`-a`, activate) to a window with class (`-x`) "Thunar". If the command fails, i.e., there is no such window, then the command after `||` is run, the command to start thunar. Find the correct window class (not sure if "Thunar" is valid) in the output of `wmctrl -lx`.

**Adapting the launcher**

You now can customize the launcher for Thunar in your menu. Launchers are text files with the `.desktop` extension. They live (among others) in `/usr/share/applications`. Copy the launcher of Thunar to your `~/.local/share/applications` folder:

```
cp /usr/share/application/thunar.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then edit the copy and change the `Exec=` line to something like:

```
Exec=sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Thunar || thunar %U"
```

You enclose the command (which in reality is two commands) in a call to bash (`sh -c`) because launchers do not support having more than one command on the Exec is line. `thunar %U` should be the command that originally appeared in the launcher.

**Adapting a hotkey to launch Thunar"

If you use a hotkey to launch Thunar, you can instead specify `sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Thunar || thunar` as the command. Now, pressing the hotkey will bring a running instance in front if any is there.

*Optional tip*

Instead of directly using `wmctrl`, I use the bash script `jumpapp` (https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp), which does the same but on steroids. Subsequent invocations will cycle through all open windows. The script has different options to cope with the particular behaviour of different applications.